# Downloading a public shared file from Google Drive (encountering 500 error)

Tags: api, google-api, google-drive-api

I run this request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1TcBDyugpHQSyUCLZcM0XtHOXo0S9Neh6asQUAYh54EM/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf&key=[apiKey]
```

on this public file:

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TcBDyugpHQSyUCLZcM0XtHOXo0S9Neh6asQUAYh54EM/edit

which is clearly exportable as PDF.  I run this same query via Google's API explorer: [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)

With whatever credentials it grabs, it tells me the response is 200 OK with application/pdf data.  However, running the query manually in the browser gives me:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

I had a similar problem with a 400 using the normal File.get method:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1TcBDyugpHQSyUCLZcM0XtHOXo0S9Neh6asQUAYh54EM?alt=media&key=[api key]
```

returning:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Am I just doing something wrong?  Any help appreciated!

Comment: Error 500 is a server error being temporarily unavailable. You have to implement a [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff?hl=en) to resend the request.

Comment: I only ran the query manually, with as much as an hour in between.   Think Google's query limit is supposed to be 10 QPS for my account.

Comment: Requests to the API must be authenticated. If you run it directly in the browser, it won't contain the necessary headers.

Answer (score 0):

API key is used for accessing PUBLIC data.  Unless your file is set to public your not going get it using an API key.   You will need to be authenticated using Oauth2 and use an access token

> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1TcBDyugpHQSyUCLZcM0XtHOXo0S9Neh6asQUAYh54EM?alt=media&access_token=[token]

[Error documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request):

> 400: Bad Request
>
> User error. This can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.